# How to resize iAds banner in IOS 4.2

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, banner-ads, adbannerview

Can we resize the iAds banner frame like (200,50). Verified all properties of AddBanner View. its having only ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait and ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, But not having any frame adjusting property. My requirement like in iPad i need to split the view explicitly with out using SplitViewController. their my iAds taking complete full size of (768,66), But requested is (460,66). So how t achieve this requirement. please provide solution for this.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Use adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | 
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

Also check http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/11/27/iad-framework-updates-for-ios-42.html link its use for you.

Comment: After using autoresizingMask also it wont effect to banner AD. Finally Concluded that, it is not possible expected, but if want to banner Ads we need to customize it using third party add frameworks.